# undefined symbol

Tags: ros, ros-comm, log4cxx, update

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I updated hydro this morning then I run "rosrun lms1xx LMS1xx_node .." I get error.

error:

/home/xx/catkin_ws/devel/lib/lms1xx/LMS1xx_node: symbol lookup error: /home/xx/catkin_ws/devel/lib/lms1xx/LMS1xx_node: undefined symbol: _ZN3ros7console5printEPNS0_10FilterBaseEPN7log4cxx6LoggerENS0_6levels5LevelEPKciS9_S9_z

This node run before update. is this a bug? what can I do?

thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/121266/undefined-symbol/) by [katsumoto](https://answers.ros.org/users/6931/katsumoto/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2014-01-22

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [katsumoto](https://answers.ros.org/users/6931/katsumoto/) on 2014-01-22**:
how can I return before update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yesterday I also had some weird symbol lookup errors, too (After pulling some updates with the update manager).

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

and

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

together with erasing build dirs and rebuilding in my workspace by (in the catkin_ws folder:)

```
rm -r devel
rm -r build
catkin_make
```

solved the issue...

(See http://answers.ros.org/question/120541/problem-of-running-rosrun-turtlesim-turtlesim_node/?answer=120596#post-id-120596)

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-01-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [katsumoto](https://answers.ros.org/users/6931/katsumoto/) on 2014-01-23**:
Problem solved. Thanks.

**Comment by [carsten](https://answers.ros.org/users/11056/carsten/) on 2014-01-23**:
Had the same problem after upgrading hydro-packages. Now solved. Thank you.

**Comment by [Mago Nick](https://answers.ros.org/users/5206/mago-nick/) on 2014-01-26**:
I Still get the error, I am running ubuntu 12.04 LTS, any suggestions?